# Styling the second "cite" in HTML--Cannot change HTML, or add JavaScript

Tags: html, css

I basically have 3 blockquotes with their appropriate citations, and I want to only style the second citation. It'd be easy normally, but this is part of an HTML exercise and I cannot modify any HTML (i.e. adding classes or ids) or add any JavaScript. I can only change the CSS (again for the sake of the exercise). The link to the JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/gk0bwtvs/75/

I think I have it pretty close with the following CSS selector:

```
#left blockquote ~ blockquote cite {
  color: brown;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

This is doing what I think it should do--style all citations except the first one. However I want to take this one step further. I want to not style the last one, effectively styling the center one only. AGAIN: I cannot change any HTMl or add any JavaScript, otherwise this would be a cakewalk. I think something like the following should work, although in practice it doesn't:

```
#left blockquote ~ blockquote cite:not(cite+main) {
  color: brown;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I think that should skip the first citation because of the General sibling selector, and the last one because of the exclusion of any citations next to a main element, but it does not work. Any ideas?

**EDIT: I cannot use nth-child or nth-of-type selectors.**

Thanks,

brld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: since you can't use `nth-*` selectors, I would say use immediate sibling selectors, like so:

```
#left h2 + blockquote + blockquote cite { ... }
```

Options with `nth-*` selectors:

You could use the `nth-child` selector:

```
#left blockquote:nth-child(3) cite {
  color: brown;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Note, I used `nth-child(3)` because there is an element before the blockquotes. There is also a `nth-of-type` selector that you may wish to use, though I automatically default to nth-child for old compatibility.

Comment: Thank you! Your second option worked, solely because I forgot to mention that I am not allowed to use nth-child or nth-of-type selectors. Thank you again!

Comment: Oh, I tried to upvote you but since I don't have 15 reputation it automatically downvoted it.

Comment: I don't understand why that happens.

Comment: same here! i don't know why is the down voting!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace it with :

```
#left blockquote:nth-of-type(2) cite {
  color: brown;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ho4n91xy/)

You can read more about nth-of-type [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `nth-of-type` selector

```
#left blockquote:nth-of-type(2) cite {
  color: brown;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/s5vvasyn/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this since you can't use nth:

```
[title='testimonials'] + blockquote cite
```

1^----------------------------^2^3^-----------^4^--^

> Select the `<cite>`[4] of the `<blockquote>`[3] that immediately`+`[2] follows the element that has a `title='testimonials'`[1].

Always look for unique characteristics of elements surrounding the target element and exploit it.

#### SNIPPET

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #545454;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Consolas', sans-serif;
  color: #5585fc;
}
main > h2:nth-child(2)+p {
  color: red;
}
a[href*="//"]:not([href*="dgmd.com"]):after {
  content: " (external link)";
}
table tr td {
  padding: 5px;
}
table {
  border: pink 5px;
  border-style: double;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
main p:last-of-type em {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
}
[title='testimonials'] + blockquote cite {
  color: brown;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}
table tr + tr > th {
  text-align: left;
  font-style: italic;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Assignment 1</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>My Fine Web Page</h1>
      <h2>An Exploration of CSS Selectors</h2>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_parent">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_parent">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_self">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <aside id="left">
      <h2>What they're saying about us</h2>
      <blockquote title="testimonials">
        <p>&quot;CSS coding is endlessly fun. I have such a great time doing it.&quot;</p>
        <cite>DGMD student</cite>
      </blockquote>
      <blockquote>
        <p>&quot;I will be so glad when this assignment is over. &quot;</p>
        <cite>Another student</cite>
      </blockquote>
      <blockquote>
        <p>&quot;Do you really need so many classes and IDs after learning these cool selectors?&quot;</p>
        <cite>Jen Kramer</cite>
      </blockquote>
    </aside>
    <main>
      <h2>First Heading</h2>
      <p><em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</em>, consectetur adipiscing elit. <strong class="featured">Donec a feugiat mi.</strong> In sagittis congue blandit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. <a href="pdffile.pdf">Integer massa massa</a>,
        facilisis auctor ultricies non, convallis sed massa. Duis iaculis dignissim nisi id pretium. Mauris orci turpis, interdum quis condimentum at, mattis non mauris. Vestibulum faucibus lectus sit amet velit venenatis sed ultricies lectus ullamcorper.
        Maecenas lectus arcu, venenatis mattis rhoncus sed, vulputate nec sem. Donec euismod, <strong>nisi vitae molestie</strong> pretium, nisi eros vehicula libero, nec <em>make me green and bold</em>.</p>
      <h2>Second Heading</h2>
      <p>Tempus id bibendum a, condimentum eu enim. Nam non nunc in leo tincidunt posuere. Tempus id bibendum a, condimentum eu enim. Nam non nunc in leo tincidunt posuere.</p>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suspendisse" target="_blank">Suspendisse</a> nunc est, blandit consequat dapibus sed, pulvinar vitae felis.</li>
        <li>In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</li>
        <li>Sed dignissim egestas <a href="human.html">human</a> ac eleifend.</li>
        <li>Ut ut metus in ipsum ornare vulputate nec quis tortor.</li>
      </ul>
      <p>Pellentesque euismod suscipit lacus, et aliquam urna tempor id. Mauris nec orci erat. Donec eleifend nunc non quam dictum tempor <em>sollicitudin</em> quam blandit. Fusce id urna felis, eu vestibulum velit. Nunc ut erat a ante accumsan suscipit vitae
        in neque. Proin convallis mollis enim et sodales. Sed eu nisl et sapien ornare euismod sit amet in velit. Praesent dignissim porta commodo.</p>
      <p>Praesent adipiscing, enim in varius pulvinar, mauris quam pharetra lectus, quis tempor nulla risus at est. <a href="anotherpdf.pdf">Aenean felis eros</a>, cursus non cursus ac, condimentum et ipsum. Proin eget nunc dignissim nisl consectetur ullamcorper.
        Nulla sit amet lacinia sapien. Nulla vitae dolor velit. Maecenas adipiscing, lacus vitae rutrum tempor, leo massa facilisis ligula, sed interdum nisi purus consectetur tortor. Curabitur accumsan libero eu erat mattis vitae semper est eleifend.</p>
      <h2>A Table Is Cool</h2>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <th>January</th>
          <th>March</th>
          <th>June</th>
          <th>September</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Temperature</th>
          <td>Cold</td>
          <td>Maple syrup season!</td>
          <td>Warmer</td>
          <td>Cooling down</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Precipitation</th>
          <td>Snow</td>
          <td>Mud</td>
          <td>Rain</td>
          <td>Rain, but not for long</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Amount of Daylight</th>
          <td>Very little</td>
          <td>Even daylight and night</td>
          <td>Lots of daylight</td>
          <td>Even daylight and night</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Recommended Outerwear</th>
          <td>Heavy jacket</td>
          <td>It depends!</td>
          <td>Usually no jacket</td>
          <td>Light jacket sometimes</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <h2>Aenean condimentum dignissim tincidunt</h2>
      <p><a href="document.html">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</a> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus ut dui dolor, vel gravida dolor. In blandit, ipsum et congue viverra, quam lectus luctus ipsum, at vehicula nisl massa
        at nunc. Etiam pulvinar sem vitae massa cursus gravida. Suspendisse id eros id ligula tristique vehicula. Etiam viverra placerat blandit. <em>Maecenas</em> cursus neque et lectus placerat ultricies. <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Vivamus feugiat</a>,
        magna non sollicitudin egestas, lectus leo aliquet nisl, vitae ultricies dui purus in sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur varius, risus at facilisis adipiscing, justo velit consectetur
        nisl, et tristique nibh neque ut odio. Cras venenatis leo at purus fermentum non rhoncus eros tincidunt. Praesent sed leo at tortor euismod pellentesque eget sit amet sem. Proin eget tortor vitae risus mattis sagittis sed non neque. Cras sed neque
        velit.
      </p>
      <p>Praesent ut <em>give me a purple background</em>. In gravida quam id risus suscipit eget feugiat diam lobortis. Morbi non libero eu dui scelerisque tincidunt eu quis turpis. Mauris posuere adipiscing lobortis. Donec accumsan, orci et sagittis imperdiet,
        eros nunc venenatis mauris, et pretium lectus velit vel turpis. Pellentesque tristique sapien eget tellus faucibus volutpat. Aenean nulla tellus, facilisis ut accumsan at, volutpat ac ante.</p>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <p>&copy; 2016 by me. All rights reserved, baby!</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```